# How to split a report page in two

Tags: tables, tabularx, block

I am trying to divide my page in containers like in the above image
[image]

In the left side will be an image and in the right side will be a table. I need a nice way to display this image. I tried to use `\Block` to solve this problem but didn't work.
I have 4 tables with 12 columns and only 3 images, so the last container should only contain the table.
I don't really know how to divide this page in order to divide the page and to fit in tables in my container.
If someone can help me with this it will be just great.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please give MWE !

Comment: you can use for example tikz matrix with node name and place them in wich distance you want. Every table has 12 columns ?

Answer (score 2):

Is that you want ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,matrix,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}

Title
\end{center}

\tikzset{mymatrix/.style={ampersand replacement=\&,nodes in empty cells, matrix of nodes,
    nodes = { gray, draw, align=center,  minimum height=4cm,
        anchor=center,
        minimum width=5cm,
        inner sep=0pt,}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (a) [mymatrix]{ sized image\\};
\matrix (b) [mymatrix,right=of a,node distance=3cm]{  \node (){ \begin{tabular}{llllllllllll}
1 & 2 & 3 &4  & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &
\end{tabular} };\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the distance between title and the  environment, and the node distance.

Comment: Looks very good. Do you think is possible that containers to be able to auto resize depending in there content and also to be align to the left of the page?

Comment: I do that on the fly. I don't know the size of your tabular environment ! You can produce a minimal work example. If done I can try helping you.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thanks for your help @Haouam